# Determine the power dissipated in W in the 5 Ω resistor

Tags: power, capacitor, resistors, phasor, reactive-power

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK0u7C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Excuse me for my really bad use of the schematic feature I just didn't know how to switch to the phasor domain. Anyway, I'm asked to find the Power at the R2 Resistor knowing only that the capacitor absorbs -2.3 VARs of reactive power.

I've been stuck on this problem and just couldn't find a way to solve it so I just need something to focus at or maybe get some power properties I should know.

(And yes, we don't know how many volts the source is generating)

Comment: The power source in the schematic is dc, there is no reactance here. I’m guessing you’re referring to an ac source instead.

Comment: Yes I do mean that, this is my first time using a schematic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like a homework question without an attempt at a solution

Comment: I see you're not the friendly type

Comment: I've updated the schematic to show V2 as AC.  Do you know the frequency?  Also if the values of L1 and C1 are Henry and Farad there should be no **j** in there.  If they are impedances it should be ohms.

Answer (score 5):

V2, L1, and R1 are red herrings - don't pay attention to them. You know the reactive power dissipated by the capacitor as well as its reactance. This yields the RMS voltage across the capacitor by Ohm's law. But the capacitor is in parallel with R2, so you immediately know the RMS voltage across the resistor. With the resistance and RMS voltage, you can easily determine the average power dissipation in the resistor.